# what is it? ['Y','N'] if( uc( $ENV{USERNAME} ) =~ /$super_users/i )

Tags: perl

I am tracing the program which does not belong to me. What the below expression means:

```
get_input(
   \$args_100{env}, 
   "\n\tAre these reports running out of the TEST environment (Y\/N)?",
   0,
   'N',
   '',
   ['Y','N']
) if( uc( $ENV{USERNAME} ) =~ /$super_users/i ) ;
```

I understand if statement but before if?

Comment: what is the line before it?

Comment: Is it the last line in a subroutine ?

Comment: this is the full line:             get_input(\$args_100{env}, "\n\tAre these reports running out of the TEST environment (Y\/N) ?",0,'N','',['Y','N']) if(  uc( $ENV{USERNAME} ) =~ /$super_users/i  ) ;

Comment: Note that the `uc` is useless, since the match is case-insensitive (`/i`)

Answer (score 6):

It is postfix if notation. See [Statement Modifiers in `perlsyn`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlsyn#Statement-Modifiers). It is equivalent to

```
if ( uc( $ENV{USERNAME} ) =~ /$super_users/i ) {
    get_input(\$args_100{env}, 
        "\n\tAre these reports running out of the TEST environment (Y\/N) ?",
        0, 'N','',['Y','N']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that `['Y','N']` creates an array of two single-character strings, `"Y"` and `"N"`, and returns a reference to that array. That reference is being passed as the sixth and last parameter to the call to `get_input`

```
get_input(
   \$args_100{env}, 
   "\n\tAre these reports running out of the TEST environment (Y\/N)?",
   0,
   'N',
   '',
   ['Y','N']
) if( uc( $ENV{USERNAME} ) =~ /$super_users/i ) ;
```